# Organização de tabelas de formulário do mautic em um site HTML

Tags: css, html5

## Gostaria de deixar o formulário dessa forma ##

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    <!-- ***** Contact Area End *****  -->
    <section class="contact_us_area section_padding_90_0" id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Heading Text -->
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="section-heading text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
                        <span>Contact</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                    <!-- Contact Form -->
                    <div class="contact_from_area clearfix">
                        <div class="contact_form">
                            <form action="http://demo.designing-world.com/rexplus-preview/rexplus/mail.php" method="post" id="main_contact_form">
                                <div class="contact_input_area">
                                    <div id="success_fail_info"></div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <div class="conatct_heading">
                                                <h2>Drop Line Here</h2>
                                            </div>

        </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /** This section is only needed once per page if manually copying **/
    if (typeof MauticSDKLoaded == 'undefined') {
        var MauticSDKLoaded = true;
        var head            = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var script          = document.createElement('script');
        script.type         = 'text/javascript';
        script.src          = 'http://painelcontrol.editorasignos.com.br/media/js/mautic-form.js';
        script.onload       = function() {
            MauticSDK.onLoad();
        };
        head.appendChild(script);
        var MauticDomain = 'http://painelcontrol.editorasignos.com.br';
        var MauticLang   = {
            'submittingMessage': "Por favor, aguarde..."
        }
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css" scoped>
    .mauticform_wrapper { max-width: 600px; margin: 10px auto; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #676767;}
    .mauticform-innerform {}
    .mauticform-post-success {}
    .mauticform-name { font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.5em; margin-bottom: 3px; }
    .mauticform-description { margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
    .mauticform-error { margin-bottom: 10px; color: red; }
    .mauticform-message { margin-bottom: 10px;color: green; }
    .mauticform-row { display: block; margin-bottom: 20px; }
    .mauticform-label { font-size: 1.1em; display: block; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 5px; }
    .mauticform-row.mauticform-required .mauticform-label:after { color: #e32; content: " *"; display: inline; }
    .mauticform-helpmessage { display: block; font-size: 0.9em; margin-bottom: 3px; }
    .mauticform-errormsg { display: block; color: red; margin-top: 2px; }
    .mauticform-selectbox, .mauticform-input, .mauticform-textarea { width: 100%; padding: 0.5em 0.5em; border: 1px solid #CCC; background: #fff; box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff inset; border-radius: 4px; box-sizing: border-box; }
    .mauticform-checkboxgrp-row {}
    .mauticform-checkboxgrp-label { font-weight: normal; }
    .mauticform-checkboxgrp-checkbox {}
    .mauticform-radiogrp-row {}
    .mauticform-radiogrp-label { font-weight: normal; }
    .mauticform-radiogrp-radio {}
    .mauticform-button-wrapper .mauticform-button.btn-default { color: #5d6c7c;background-color: #ffffff;border-color: #dddddd;}
    .mauticform-button-wrapper .mauticform-button { display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 600;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 13px;line-height: 1.3856;border-radius: 3px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;}
    .mauticform-button-wrapper .mauticform-button.btn-default[disabled] { background-color: #ffffff; border-color: #dddddd;}
</style>
<style type="text/css" scoped>
    .mauticform_wrapper { max-width: 600px; margin: 10px auto; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #676767;}
    .mauticform-innerform {}
    .mauticform-post-success {}
    .mauticform-name { font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.5em; margin-bottom: 3px; }
    .mauticform-description { margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
    .mauticform-error { margin-bottom: 10px; color: red; }
    .mauticform-message { margin-bottom: 10px;color: green; }
    .mauticform-row { display: block; margin-bottom: 20px; }
    .mauticform-label { font-size: 1.1em; display: block; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 5px; }
    .mauticform-row.mauticform-required .mauticform-label:after { color: #e32; content: " *"; display: inline; }
    .mauticform-helpmessage { display: block; font-size: 0.9em; margin-bottom: 3px; }
    .mauticform-errormsg { display: block; color: red; margin-top: 2px; }
    .mauticform-selectbox, .mauticform-input, .mauticform-textarea { width: 100%; padding: 0.5em 0.5em; border: 1px solid #CCC; background: #fff; box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff inset; border-radius: 4px; box-sizing: border-box; }
    .mauticform-checkboxgrp-row {}
    .mauticform-checkboxgrp-label { font-weight: normal; }
    .mauticform-checkboxgrp-checkbox {}
    .mauticform-radiogrp-row {}
    .mauticform-radiogrp-label { font-weight: normal; }
    .mauticform-radiogrp-radio {}
    .mauticform-button-wrapper .mauticform-button.btn-default { color: #5d6c7c;background-color: #ffffff;border-color: #dddddd;}
    .mauticform-button-wrapper .mauticform-button { display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 600;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 13px;line-height: 1.3856;border-radius: 3px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;}
    .mauticform-button-wrapper .mauticform-button.btn-default[disabled] { background-color: #ffffff; border-color: #dddddd;}
</style>

<!-- FORMULARIO-->

<style type="text/css" scoped>
    .mauticform_wrapper { max-width: 600px; margin: 10px auto; color: #6f6f6f; font-weight: 400; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';font-size: 18px;}
    .mauticform-innerform {}
    .mauticform-post-success {}
    .mauticform-name { font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.5em; margin-bottom: 3px; }
    .mauticform-description { margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
    .mauticform-error { margin-bottom: 10px; color: red; }
    .mauticform-message { margin-bottom: 10px;color: green; }
    .mauticform-row { display: block; margin-bottom: 20px; }
    .mauticform-label { font-size: 1.1em; display: block; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 5px; color: #21c5ba; }
    .mauticform-row.mauticform-required .mauticform-label:after { color: #e32; content: " *"; display: inline; }
    .mauticform-helpmessage { display: block; font-size: 0.9em; margin-bottom: 3px; }
    .mauticform-errormsg { display: block; color: red; margin-top: 2px; }
    .mauticform-selectbox, .mauticform-input, .mauticform-textarea { width: 100%; padding: 0.5em 0.5em; border: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #21c5ba; background: #fff; box-sizing: border-box; }
    .mauticform-checkboxgrp-row {}
    .mauticform-checkboxgrp-label { font-weight: normal; }
    .mauticform-checkboxgrp-checkbox {}
    .mauticform-radiogrp-row {}
    .mauticform-radiogrp-label { font-weight: normal; }
    .mauticform-radiogrp-radio {}
    .mauticform-button-wrapper .mauticform-button.btn-default { color: #21c5ba;background-color: #ffffff;border-color: #21c5ba;}
    .mauticform-button-wrapper .mauticform-button { display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 600;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 18px;line-height: 1.3856;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;}
    .mauticform-button-wrapper .mauticform-button.btn-default[disabled] { background-color: #ffffff; border-color: #dddddd;}
</style>

<div id="mauticform_wrapper_formularioorcamento" class="mauticform_wrapper">
    <form autocomplete="false" role="form" method="post" action="http://painelcontrol.editorasignos.com.br/form/submit?formId=1" id="mauticform_formularioorcamento"  data-mautic-form="formularioorcamento" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="mauticform-error" id="mauticform_formularioorcamento_error"></div>
        <div class="mauticform-message" id="mauticform_formularioorcamento_message"></div>
        <div class="mauticform-innerform">


          <div class="mauticform-page-wrapper mauticform-page-1" data-mautic-form-page="1">

            <div id="mauticform_formularioorcamento_nome"  class="mauticform-row mauticform-text mauticform-field-1">
                <label id="mauticform_label_formularioorcamento_nome" for="mauticform_input_formularioorcamento_nome" class="mauticform-label">Nome</label>
                <input id="mauticform_input_formularioorcamento_nome" name="mauticform[nome]" value="" class="mauticform-input" type="text" />
                <span class="mauticform-errormsg" style="display: none;"></span>
            </div>

            <div id="mauticform_formularioorcamento_email"  class="mauticform-row mauticform-email mauticform-field-2">
                <label id="mauticform_label_formularioorcamento_email" for="mauticform_input_formularioorcamento_email" class="mauticform-label">e-mail</label>
                <input id="mauticform_input_formularioorcamento_email" name="mauticform[email]" value="" class="mauticform-input" type="email" />
                <span class="mauticform-errormsg" style="display: none;"></span>
            </div>

            <div id="mauticform_formularioorcamento_numero_de_celular"  class="mauticform-row mauticform-number mauticform-field-3">
                <label id="mauticform_label_formularioorcamento_numero_de_celular" for="mauticform_input_formularioorcamento_numero_de_celular" class="mauticform-label">Numero de Celular</label>
                <input id="mauticform_input_formularioorcamento_numero_de_celular" name="mauticform[numero_de_celular]" value="" class="mauticform-input" type="number" />
                <span class="mauticform-errormsg" style="display: none;"></span>
            </div>

            <div id="mauticform_formularioorcamento_sobre_a_capa1"  class="mauticform-row mauticform-radiogrp mauticform-field-4">
                <label  class="mauticform-label" for="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_sobre_a_capa1_Queroquecriem1">Sobre a capa</label>
                <div class="mauticform-radiogrp-row">
                    <label id="mauticform_radiogrp_label_sobre_a_capa1_Queroquecriem0" for="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_sobre_a_capa1_Queroquecriem0"  class="mauticform-radiogrp-label">
                        <input  name="mauticform[sobre_a_capa1]" class="mauticform-radiogrp-radio" name="mauticform[sobre_a_capa1]" id="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_sobre_a_capa1_Queroquecriem0" type="radio" value="Quero que criem" />
                        Quero que criem
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="mauticform-radiogrp-row">
                    <label id="mauticform_radiogrp_label_sobre_a_capa1_Jatenhoumacapa1" for="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_sobre_a_capa1_Jatenhoumacapa1"  class="mauticform-radiogrp-label">
                        <input  name="mauticform[sobre_a_capa1]" class="mauticform-radiogrp-radio" name="mauticform[sobre_a_capa1]" id="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_sobre_a_capa1_Jatenhoumacapa1" type="radio" value="Já tenho uma capa" />
                        Já tenho uma capa
                    </label>
                </div>
                <span class="mauticform-errormsg" style="display: none;"></span>
            </div>

            <div id="mauticform_formularioorcamento_categoria_do_seu_livro"  class="mauticform-row mauticform-checkboxgrp mauticform-field-5">
                <label  class="mauticform-label" for="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_categoria_do_seu_livro_Ficcao1">Categoria do seu livro</label>
                <span class="mauticform-helpmessage">Marque a opção ideal que mais se encaixa com as características do seu livro</span>
                <div class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-row">
                    <label id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_label_categoria_do_seu_livro_ficcao0" for="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_categoria_do_seu_livro_ficcao0"  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-label">
                        <input  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-checkbox" name="mauticform[categoria_do_seu_livro][]" id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_categoria_do_seu_livro_ficcao0" type="checkbox" value="ficção" />
                        Ficção
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-row">
                    <label id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_label_categoria_do_seu_livro_revistas1" for="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_categoria_do_seu_livro_revistas1"  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-label">
                        <input  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-checkbox" name="mauticform[categoria_do_seu_livro][]" id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_categoria_do_seu_livro_revistas1" type="checkbox" value="revistas" />
                        Revistas
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-row">
                    <label id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_label_categoria_do_seu_livro_poesia2" for="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_categoria_do_seu_livro_poesia2"  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-label">
                        <input  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-checkbox" name="mauticform[categoria_do_seu_livro][]" id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_categoria_do_seu_livro_poesia2" type="checkbox" value="poesia" />
                        Poesia
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-row">
                    <label id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_label_categoria_do_seu_livro_drama3" for="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_categoria_do_seu_livro_drama3"  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-label">
                        <input  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-checkbox" name="mauticform[categoria_do_seu_livro][]" id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_categoria_do_seu_livro_drama3" type="checkbox" value="drama" />
                        Drama
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-row">
                    <label id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_label_categoria_do_seu_livro_outros4" for="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_categoria_do_seu_livro_outros4"  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-label">
                        <input  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-checkbox" name="mauticform[categoria_do_seu_livro][]" id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_categoria_do_seu_livro_outros4" type="checkbox" value="outros" />
                        Outros
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-row">
                    <label id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_label_categoria_do_seu_livro_romance5" for="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_categoria_do_seu_livro_romance5"  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-label">
                        <input  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-checkbox" name="mauticform[categoria_do_seu_livro][]" id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_categoria_do_seu_livro_romance5" type="checkbox" value="romance" />
                        Romance
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-row">
                    <label id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_label_categoria_do_seu_livro_acaoeaventura6" for="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_categoria_do_seu_livro_acaoeaventura6"  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-label">
                        <input  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-checkbox" name="mauticform[categoria_do_seu_livro][]" id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_categoria_do_seu_livro_acaoeaventura6" type="checkbox" value="ação e aventura" />
                        Ação e Aventura
                    </label>
                </div>
                <span class="mauticform-errormsg" style="display: none;"></span>
            </div>

            <div id="mauticform_formularioorcamento_qual_formato_voce_precisa"  class="mauticform-row mauticform-checkboxgrp mauticform-field-6">
                <label  class="mauticform-label" for="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_qual_formato_voce_precisa_Epubmobi1">Qual formato você precisa?</label>
                <span class="mauticform-helpmessage">Selecione os formatos de e-book que você precisa que, criamos do seu jeito!</span>
                <div class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-row">
                    <label id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_label_qual_formato_voce_precisa_120" for="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_qual_formato_voce_precisa_120"  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-label">
                        <input  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-checkbox" name="mauticform[qual_formato_voce_precisa][]" id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_qual_formato_voce_precisa_120" type="checkbox" value="12" />
                        Epub/mobi
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-row">
                    <label id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_label_qual_formato_voce_precisa_221" for="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_qual_formato_voce_precisa_221"  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-label">
                        <input  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-checkbox" name="mauticform[qual_formato_voce_precisa][]" id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_qual_formato_voce_precisa_221" type="checkbox" value="22" />
                        PDF
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-row">
                    <label id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_label_qual_formato_voce_precisa_322" for="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_qual_formato_voce_precisa_322"  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-label">
                        <input  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-checkbox" name="mauticform[qual_formato_voce_precisa][]" id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_qual_formato_voce_precisa_322" type="checkbox" value="32" />
                        Ibook
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-row">
                    <label id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_label_qual_formato_voce_precisa_423" for="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_qual_formato_voce_precisa_423"  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-label">
                        <input  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-checkbox" name="mauticform[qual_formato_voce_precisa][]" id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_qual_formato_voce_precisa_423" type="checkbox" value="42" />
                        outro
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-row">
                    <label id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_label_qual_formato_voce_precisa_524" for="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_qual_formato_voce_precisa_524"  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-label">
                        <input  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-checkbox" name="mauticform[qual_formato_voce_precisa][]" id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_qual_formato_voce_precisa_524" type="checkbox" value="52" />
                        Eu não tenho certeza
                    </label>
                </div>
                <span class="mauticform-errormsg" style="display: none;"></span>
            </div>

            <div id="mauticform_formularioorcamento_quantidade_de_paginas"  class="mauticform-row mauticform-number mauticform-field-7">
                <label id="mauticform_label_formularioorcamento_quantidade_de_paginas" for="mauticform_input_formularioorcamento_quantidade_de_paginas" class="mauticform-label">Quantidade de páginas</label>
                <span class="mauticform-helpmessage">Coloque quantas paginas tem seu livro</span>
                <input id="mauticform_input_formularioorcamento_quantidade_de_paginas" name="mauticform[quantidade_de_paginas]" value="Quant, pag" class="mauticform-input" type="number" />
                <span class="mauticform-errormsg" style="display: none;"></span>
            </div>

            <div id="mauticform_formularioorcamento_quantidade_de_imagens"  class="mauticform-row mauticform-number mauticform-field-8">
                <label id="mauticform_label_formularioorcamento_quantidade_de_imagens" for="mauticform_input_formularioorcamento_quantidade_de_imagens" class="mauticform-label">Quantidade de Imagens</label>
                <span class="mauticform-helpmessage">Caso seu livro não tenha imagens deixe em branco</span>
                <input id="mauticform_input_formularioorcamento_quantidade_de_imagens" name="mauticform[quantidade_de_imagens]" value="Quant, img" class="mauticform-input" type="number" />
                <span class="mauticform-errormsg" style="display: none;"></span>
            </div>

            <div id="mauticform_formularioorcamento_seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado"  class="mauticform-row mauticform-checkboxgrp mauticform-field-9">
                <label  class="mauticform-label" for="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado_Diagramar1">Seu livro já é diagramado e revisado ?</label>
                <span class="mauticform-helpmessage">Caso você quiser adicionar alguns desses serviços selecione a opção que mais se adéqua a você</span>
                <div class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-row">
                    <label id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_label_seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado_130" for="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado_130"  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-label">
                        <input  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-checkbox" name="mauticform[seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado][]" id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado_130" type="checkbox" value="13" />
                        Diagramar
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-row">
                    <label id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_label_seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado_2131" for="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado_2131"  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-label">
                        <input  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-checkbox" name="mauticform[seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado][]" id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado_2131" type="checkbox" value="213" />
                        Revisar
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-row">
                    <label id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_label_seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado_222" for="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado_222"  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-label">
                        <input  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-checkbox" name="mauticform[seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado][]" id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado_222" type="checkbox" value="22" />
                        ISBN
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-row">
                    <label id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_label_seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado_21313" for="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado_21313"  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-label">
                        <input  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-checkbox" name="mauticform[seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado][]" id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado_21313" type="checkbox" value="2131" />
                        Ilustração
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-row">
                    <label id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_label_seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado_2114" for="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado_2114"  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-label">
                        <input  class="mauticform-checkboxgrp-checkbox" name="mauticform[seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado][]" id="mauticform_checkboxgrp_checkbox_seu_livro_ja_e_diagramado_2114" type="checkbox" value="211" />
                        Assessoria literaria
                    </label>
                </div>
                <span class="mauticform-errormsg" style="display: none;"></span>
            </div>

            <div id="mauticform_formularioorcamento_submit"  class="mauticform-row mauticform-button-wrapper mauticform-field-10">
                <button type="submit" name="mauticform[submit]" id="mauticform_input_formularioorcamento_submit" name="mauticform[submit]" value="" class="mauticform-button btn btn-default" value="1">Enviar</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="mauticform[formId]" id="mauticform_formularioorcamento_id" value="1"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="mauticform[return]" id="mauticform_formularioorcamento_return" value=""/>
        <input type="hidden" name="mauticform[formName]" id="mauticform_formularioorcamento_name" value="formularioorcamento"/>

        </form>

<!-- END FORMULARIO -->
```

Comment: não deu pra entender bem o que você quer, fora que o código na pergunta está meio bagunçado. consegue fazer um exemplo que possamos ver para tentar te ajudar a resolver?

Comment: Pronto amigo criei uma imagem ilustrativa de como gostaria de deixar meu formulério